# Java: Breaking a list into "Chunks" that are sorted, to sort list completely

Tags: java, arrays, list, mergesort

Okay, first post here, so please bear with me.

So I'm trying to work this out on my own as much as possible, but I'm at a bit of a loss here. I have been given a list ( and will be given many more to test, but I'm working with this one) of 12 integers. The list is as follows:

18 21 9 12 99 4 101 8 14 7 112 98

and a chunk is defined as an already sorted grouping of integers. This means there are 6 chunks.  Since this is a recursive chunk merge sort, I need to be able to break it up based on the chunks.

The first split would look like:

18 21 9 12 99 4 101   |  8 14 7 112 98

and the second would look like:

18 21 | 9 12 99 | 4 101   |||  8 14 | 7 112 | 98

As you can see, this means six chunks. Now, I have managed to get to the first step, but it is not done via recursion, or through these chunks. I cheated and took the size of the list and cut it in half. That's a no go.

I am open to trying out any suggestion, I am just stumped at how to go about breaking this down into these chunks, especially if I cannot dictate the number of "chunks" going in.

Here's a chunk of my code, if it helps:

```
    public List<Integer> chunkMergesort(List<Integer> S) {
    int c = 0;

    if(S.size() > 1){
        c = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i<S.size()-1 ; i++){
            if(S.get(i+1)< S.get(i)){
                c++;
                System.out.println("C is: " + c);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Final C is: " + c);
        chunkDivide(S, c);
    }
        return S;
}

public Chunks chunkDivide(List<Integer> S, int c) {

    int Ssize = S.size()/2;
    System.out.println("List:"+ S);

    List<Integer> S1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> S2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i = 0; i < Ssize; i++){
        //System.out.println("i is: "+ i);
        S1.add(i, S.get(i));    
        System.out.println("S1 is:"+ S1);
    }

    for(int i = Ssize; i < S.size(); i++){
        S2.add(i-Ssize, S.get(i));
        System.out.println("S2 is:"+ S2);

    }

    System.out.println("S1 is: "+ S1);
    System.out.println("S2 is: "+ S2);      

    Chunks p = new Chunks(S1, S2);

    //chunkMergesort(S1);
    //chunkMergesort(S2);
    //chunkDivide(p.right, mid);
    //chunkDivide(p.left, mid);

    merge(S1,S2);

    return p;
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I ended up using something similar to what was suggested by @Eritrean but a whole new issue arose. My list is moved into a List of chunks, but the last item in the list (98) which should be the last chunk as well, gets dropped. I tried to ask how to fix this issue in another question, and was immediately dismissed as it being a duplicate. Those "answers" don't actually answer my question. Any more insight into this would be wonderful.

Below will be my image showing the output. 
[CMD Snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLBab.png)

Comment: Well, I'm a little confused about your algorithm (it's possible that I'm just not aware of this particular algorithm though). [Merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort), both bottom-up and top-down, doesn't really care about any "pre-existing chunks". It does it's own thing, so there's no reason to really pre-process the array like you are doing. So: Why are you trying to divide it up into pre-sorted chunks prior to applying the merge sort algorithm? Can you clear up what purpose that serves? In any case if you want to divide it up *non* recursively just look for all a[n] < a[n-1].

Comment: The fact that it's looking for pre-sorted chunks is just because it's part of the assignment. It's essentially an arbitrary rule I cannot change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through the list and look for sorted parts of the list by comparing current element by its successors. Then you can add this parts to a list of lists using the method list.subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex). Example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(18, 21, 9, 12, 99, 4, 101, 8, 14, 7, 112, 98);

        List<List<Integer>> chunks = breakIntoChunks(intList);

        for(List<Integer> chunk : chunks){
            System.out.println(chunk);
        }
    }

    private static List<List<Integer>> breakIntoChunks(List<Integer> intList) {
        List<List<Integer>> chunks = new ArrayList<>();
        int curr =0;
        for(int i = 0; i<intList.size()-1; i++){
            if(intList.get(i).compareTo(intList.get(i+1))>0 || i==intList.size()-1){
                chunks.add(intList.subList(curr, i+1));
                curr = i+1;
            }
         }
         if(curr<=intList.size()){
              chunks.add(intList.subList(curr,intList.size()));
         }
         return chunks;       
      }
  }
```

Comment: This looks like it might work, though I'm not sure about having List<List<Integer>> chunks, as I have a method that breaks the list into chunks.

Comment: /**
  * Use this class to return two lists.
  * 
  * Example of use:
  * 
  * Chunks p = new Chunks(S1, S2); // where S1 and S2 are lists of integers
  */
 public static final class Chunks {
  
  private final List<Integer> left;
  private final List<Integer> right;
  
  public Chunks(List<Integer> left, List<Integer> right) {
   this.left = left;
   this.right = right;
  }
  
  public List<Integer> left() {
   return this.left;
  }
  
  public List<Integer> right() {
   return this.right;
  }

Comment: Hey, so I was able to figure out how to use what you suggested, but I have an issue. Now it's just dropping the last element of my list, so it doesn't get added to the chunks. How can I solve that?

Comment: If you have not changed something all elements should be added. I tested the code with the list in the main method. If you have changed sth let me see what you have changed or how you intgreated it in your existing code.